# Creating an Update Record Function using Python and SQLite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently working on a coursework project for school and it is a database system with a user interface using Tkinter, Python and SQLite3. I have made a form to add, delete, update and search for customers. The update function is not producing any errors, however, the changes are not being made to the .db file. Could anyone please have a look and maybe tell me where I have went wrong? I will attach photos of the user interface and the code for the function. I'm not used to using StackOverflow, so please let me know if I have left anything out or if you need more information. Thank you in advance.

```
    def UpdateCustomer(self):
        customerid = self.CustomerEntry.get();
        town = self.TownEntry.get();
        postcode = self.PostcodeEntry.get();
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            update_customer = ('''UPDATE Customer 
            SET 
            Town = ?,
            Postcode = ?
            WHERE CustomerID = ?
            ''')
            db.commit()

            cursor.execute(update_customer,[(customerid),(town),(postcode)])
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification","Customer record updated successfully")
            self.ClearEntries()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass the parameter values that will replace the `?` placeholdrs in the exact same order as they are in the sql statement:

```
cursor.execute(update_customer, (town, postcode, customerid))
```